# mayavi volume animation not updating

Tags: animation, volume, mayavi

I’m trying to animate a Mayavi pipeline volume:

```
src = mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data),vmin=.1*np.max(data),vmax=.2*np.max(data))
```

that is combined in the pipeline by another dataset represented as a cut plane.

However, I can’t get the volume visualization to update - only the first frame shows up.  The animation is stepping through the data correctly (I get different values of the np.max(data[t]) below) but nothing in the visualization changes.

My understanding is that mlab_source_set should re-render correctly, and there’s nothing on the web anywhere that describes this (as far as I can tell).

The animation looks like:

```
@mlab.show
@mlab.animate(delay=250,ui=True)
def anim(src,data,tax,fig):
    """Animate."""
    t = 0
    nt = len(tax)
    while 1:
        vmin = .1*np.max(data[t])
        vmax = .2*np.max(data[t])
        print 'animation t = ',tax[t],', max = ',np.max(data[t])
        src.mlab_source.set(scalar = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data[t]), vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
        t = mod(t+1,nt)
        yield
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: don't use `mlab_source.set(scalar = something)`. Just set the scalars directly like `mlab_source.scalars = something`

Comment: Thank you!  That works, with one small variation:        src.mlab_source.scalars = data[t]    I appreciated the help!

Comment: do you know what traits corresponding to vmin and vmax?