# Rotation of an object in Mayavi (python)

Tags: python, graphics, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

A couple of questions:
I put together multiple parts of the available online scripts, mainly matplotlib and mayavi websites, to create the below scripts.

How can I rotate one of the shperes relative to the other by using Euler angles or the quaternion of each spheres? (I do not mean rotation of the viewpoint, just rotation of the whole object with its colormap)

or in general, 
How can I rotate one of the shperes relative to the other by an arbitrary angle?

If I set the opacity to 1.0, then the mesh points on the surface will be visible, how can I create opaque objects without loosing the surface quality? On the other hand, if I set opacity to 0.9, I have a very smooth surface, but I can see through each sphere.
I highly appreciate your help and feedback.
[opacity = 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjzaZ.png)

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import sph_harm

[theta,phi] = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:400j,0:np.pi:400j]
x = np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)

mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(400, 300))
mlab.clf()

def plot_sphere(p):
    m=0
    n=2
    s = sph_harm(m, n, theta , phi).real
    r,a,b,c = p
    return mlab.mesh(r*x+a, r*y+b, r*z+c, scalars=s, colormap='jet', resolution=50, opacity=0.9, transparent=False)  

#c = np.loadtxt("../data/d1.dat") 
c = [[10.0, 45.89, -10.99, -38.79], [10.0, 15.17, -22.34, -41.31]]
#plot_sphere(c[0])
for k in range(2):
    plot_sphere(c[k])


mlab.show()
```

**Update 1:**

I found here [Mayavi: rotate around y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790724/mayavi-rotate-around-y-axis) a method to rotate around one axis. How can I extend it to rotate the object (spheres) in 3D? either using Euler angles or quaternions. The successive use of this rotation style, to create something like rotation matrix, R(x)R(y)R(z), does not work or at least I am not well familiar with its details to do that.

By the way, where can I find more information about this syntax "actor.actor"? Is it vtk style?

Here is the code:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import sph_harm

[theta,phi] = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:400j,0:np.pi:400j]
x = np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)

mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(400, 300))
mlab.clf()

def plot_sphere(p,ang_x):
    m=0
    n=2
    s = sph_harm(m, n, theta , phi).real
    r,a,b,c = p
    m = mlab.mesh(r*x+a, r*y+b, r*z+c, scalars=s, colormap='jet', resolution=50, opacity=0.9, transparent=False)  
    mx = m.actor.actor.rotate_x(ang_x)
    return 

#c = np.loadtxt("../data/d1.dat") 
c = [[10.0, 45.89, -10.99, -38.79], [10.0, 15.17, -22.34, -41.31]]
plot_sphere(c[0],0)
plot_sphere(c[1],90)
#for k in range(2):
#    plot_sphere(c[k])


mlab.show()
```

**Update 2; possible solution:**

I think I found something which works, but I appreciate solutions using quaternions directly. I could not find detailed information about the syntax "actor", but here is my solution (we can rotate all or each individual objects by providing the rotation angles separately):

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import sph_harm

[theta,phi] = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:400j,0:np.pi:400j]
x = np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)

mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(400, 300))
mlab.clf()

def plot_sphere(p):
    m=0
    n=2
    s = sph_harm(m, n, theta , phi).real
    r,a,b,c = p
    m = mlab.mesh(r*x+a, r*y+b, r*z+c, scalars=s, colormap='jet', resolution=50, opacity=0.9, transparent=False) 
    m.actor.actor.orientation = [30,90,45] #rotate all object  "[yaw, pitch, roll]" 
    return 

#c = np.loadtxt("../data/d1.dat") 
c = [[10.0, 45.89, -10.99, -38.79], [10.0, 15.17, -22.34, -41.31]]
plot_sphere(c[0])
plot_sphere(c[1])
#for k in range(2):
#    plot_sphere(c[k])


mlab.show()
```

Comment: Update the underlying data of the sphere you would like to rotate https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_animating.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840638/update-mayavi-plot-in-loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620153/mayavi-volume-animation-not-updating

Comment: @Joe Thank you. I will check to see if I can change the animate scripts.